# el-select not showing selected label when v-model is manipulated in beforeMount()

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

`el-select` is not displaying the label of the selected option but is correctly updating the `v-model` with `el-option :value`. It is probably due to the manipulation in beforeMount() as when that is removed, the label correctly displays the option selected.

However, multiple object copies are required for my use case which is to map headers from uploaded files to expected headers where each file can have the same expected header.

Here's a fiddle with my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/c8auL7fk/

Comment: Can you explain what's not working?  What should the labels in the el-select be?

Comment: I edited the post to clarify this. I have also found an answer to my issue already and have posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a bug report for this here: https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/issues/13373 and a contributor got back to me.

Vue is unable to catch changes to dynamically created properties. Objects need to be written in an immutable manner.

More details on immutable js objects here: https://wecodetheweb.com/2016/02/12/immutable-javascript-using-es6-and-beyond/